# Captured packets with tcpdump vs. tcpdump > file

Tags: linux, tcpdump

**Why is there such difference in number of packets captured by tcpdump when the output is written to console and to file?**

```
$ tcpdump
...
1681 packets captured
1681 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

vs.

```
# tcpdump > /root/dump.txt 
...
11 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

In both cases I terminated the comand with Ctrl+C after few seconds.

Edit:
Command `tcpdump -w /root/dump.txt` also captures just few packets. This behavior is consistent, I tried many times.

Comment: There simply was more traffic flowing during your first sample. By the way, when writing tcpdump output to a file, you should be using `-w`.

Comment: I tried several times. Result is the same with -w.

Comment: What did you try?  How are you ensuring that the exact same amount of traffic is flowing for each tcpdump run?

Comment: When you run tcpdump, are you remotely logged into the machine running tcpdump, using, for example, ssh?

Comment: @GuyHarris: Yes, I am using ssh. I feel stupid. The reason for the difference is actually quite obvious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you realized, the text output from tcpdump is going over your ssh connection to the host from which you ssh'ed in to the machine on which you're running tcpdump, and thus gets captured by tcpdump.  With `-w`, tcpdump doesn't print anything per packet, so it doesn't go over the wire (unless you're saving the capture to a file on a file system mounted from a file server, such as an NFS or SMB or AFP server).

Wireshark and TShark attempt to detect that you're running Wireshark over X11 or TShark over ssh and, if you are, tweaks the capture filter under the hood to filter out X11 or ssh traffic to the host from which you're running them.  For tcpdump, you might want to use a filter such as

```
not (host {host from which you're sshing} and port ssh)
```

or, if you're already using a filter, AND that filter with the one you're using, to filter out your SSH traffic.

Comment: SSH is only detected and provided as a hint to Wireshark GTK/QT, not tshark.